# Is there a way to allow users to specify their own per-site configurations in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I'm looking for a way to allow users on a Debian system to configure their own NGINX sites.  Would the following configuration work?

```
http {
  # ...

  server {
    server_name www.alicesite.com;
    location / {
      include /home/alice/nginx.conf;
    }
  }

  server {
    server_name www.bobsite.com;
    location / {
      include /home/bob/nginx.conf;
    }
  }

  # etc.
}
```

Or some variation of it?

Comment: Not that I know of - and I have only average Nginx knowledge. A syntax error would take Nginx down, and they would need root to restart it. They'd be better off running their own Nginx instance on another port, but that makes public hosting more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. But because of some already mentioned issues you have to script and modify sudo configuration around Nginx.

The Debian/Ubuntu type of webserver configuration works with a main Nginx configuration file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) and virtual Web server configurations will be handled by including all files of the directory /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

There are additional includes, but I'd like to focus on /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* where one file represents one virtual Web server (e.g. www.bobsite.com).

For our web projects we store web server configuration files within the project folder (e.g. /var/www/project-bob/cfg/srv/nginx/sites-enabled/www.bobsite.com.conf) and create a symbolic link into the folder /etc/ngix/sites-enabled (e.g. /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.bobsite.com.conf).

After setting up the symlink we run a dry config test with Nginx (nginx -t) and if it doesn't fail we reload Nginx (service nginx reload). If the test fails we remove the symlink and responds with an exception to the project deployment interface.

As all this requires root privileges we have created a sudoers configuration file (see /etc/sudoers.d) to grant limited sudo privileges to the deployment interface.